# Can't figure out how to do attachments with MvcMailer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcmailer

Exactly how, and where, do I place the actual file location for the string `attachmentPath`:

```
public virtual MailMessage Welcome(string attachmentPath)
    {
        var mailMessage = new MailMessage{Subject = "Welcome to MvcMailer"};
        ...
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentPath));
        PopulateBody(mailMessage, "Welcome");
        return mailMessage;
    }
```

Presume a physical file location on the server of `c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace attachmentPath with @"c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf" like this:

Change attachmentPath

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentPath));
```

to @"c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf"

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment((Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory) + "\docs\") + attachmentFile))
```

Where attachmentFile is your file `test.pdf`.

c:\inetpub\server\website\docs\test.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Where exactly am I "declaring" (if that's what it is) `attachmentFile`? And how do I "declare" it?